# Save Origin Point in Blender

Tags: object-mode, origin

I have successfully set the pivot point to the 3D cursor. However, when I export the OBJ file and then re-import it, the pivot point is not stabilized.
This also happens when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and apply all transforms.

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wavefront OBJ format doesn't support "transformations", among other things. To make it simple, it exports only basic geometry at world center and some basic material information, that's it.

> There is no support for armatures, lights, cameras, empty objects, parenting, or transformations. See [Compatibility](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export/obj.html#compatibility) for more information.
>
> ---
>
> Source: **[Wavefront OBJ — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export/obj.html)**

If you need more than that, you must use a different format for export. There are plenty of them, FBX is the common industry standard for this.

---

> This also happens when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and apply all transforms.

`Apply All Transforms` applies the location, rotation, scale. Applying the location literally means setting the object's origin to the world center:

> Apply (set) the location of the selection. This will make Blender consider the current location to be equivalent to 0 in each plane i.e. the selection will not move, the current location will be considered to be the “default location”. The object origin will be set to actual (0, 0, 0) (where the colored axis lines intersect in each view).
>
> ---
>
> Source: **[Apply — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/4.0/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html?utm_source=blender-4.0.2#options)**

If you don't want that, you can use `Apply Rotation & Scale`. Or apply the individual transforms you want.

Answer (score 2):

It looks, according to [this page of Blenderartists](https://blenderartists.org/t/obj-export-issue-object-origins-and-axes-reset/1328550/5), that .obj don't keep the origin location, if you can, export as .fbx instead.